# Python Flask: How to easily consume dozens of HTML form fields and use them in a DB call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a form with several dozen fields and in my route I collect them as follows

```
conditions_angina= request.form["conditions-angina"]
conditions_cancer= request.form["conditions-cancer"]
conditions_stroke= request.form["conditions-stroke"]
...
```

Then later I do what I need to do with my DB insert

```
sql = EXEC uspInsertData ?,?,?....
params = (conditions_angina,conditions_cancer,conditions_stroke...
sql_result = Conn.testsql(db="TestPython", sql=sql, params=params)
```

This all works fine but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this for several dozen fields or any number of fields

We don't use [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/) we just add them manually for now with Bootstrap 4 styling

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a form you can use `request.form` to get all of the keys/values from the form (see `request.form` [usage here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.Request.form)) instead of specifically assigning each form field to a variable like you're doing now. It's an `ImmutableMultiDict` [ref here](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict).

In your `route` or `endpoint` to get all of the fields it would look like this:

```
conditions = request.form
```

Now your conditions object will look like:

```
conditions = {"form_field_1": "form_value_1", "form_field_2": "form_value_2"}
```

from which you can insert your data accordingly.